# selecting data from a R data table from a set of variables occurring at same timestamp

Tags: r, datatable

I have a R data table like this:

```
time                var val
01-07-2019 13:27:31 X   5
01-07-2019 13:27:31 Y   10
01-07-2019 13:27:31 Z   12
01-07-2019 13:28:20 X   13
01-07-2019 13:28:20 Y   12
01-07-2019 13:28:20 Z   15
01-07-2019 13:49:54 X   3
01-07-2019 13:49:54 Y   3
01-07-2019 13:49:54 Z   4
01-07-2019 13:50:25 X   13
01-07-2019 13:50:25 Y   11
01-07-2019 13:50:25 Z   10
```

The set of variable repeat over same time. SO at each time stamp one set will be there.
How to extract rows matching conditions like `X>10 & Y<15` in same `timestamp`?

Output expected :

```
time                var val
01-07-2019 13:28:20 X   13
01-07-2019 13:28:20 Y   12
01-07-2019 13:28:20 Z   15
01-07-2019 13:50:25 X   13
01-07-2019 13:50:25 Y   11
01-07-2019 13:50:25 Z   10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to make it when using `base R`:

**Solution 1**: You can reshape your `df` first and use `subset` to meet the criteria

```
u <- subset(reshape(df,idvar = "time",timevar = "var", direction = "wide"),val.X>10, val.Y < 15)
> u
                  time val.X val.Y val.Z
4  01-07-2019 13:28:20    13    12    15
10 01-07-2019 13:50:25    13    11    10
```

then

```
> df[!is.na(match(df$time,u$time)),]
                  time var val
4  01-07-2019 13:28:20   X  13
5  01-07-2019 13:28:20   Y  12
6  01-07-2019 13:28:20   Z  15
10 01-07-2019 13:50:25   X  13
11 01-07-2019 13:50:25   Y  11
12 01-07-2019 13:50:25   Z  10
```

**Solution 2**: You can also use `split` to split the data frame by `time`

```
z <- split(df,df$time)
Reduce(rbind,z[sapply(z,function(v) with(v,ifelse(val[var=="X"]>10 & val[var=="Y"]<15,T,F)))])
```

then

```
> Reduce(rbind,z[sapply(z,function(v) with(v,ifelse(val[var=="X"]>10 & val[var=="Y"]<15,T,F)))])
                  time var val
4  01-07-2019 13:28:20   X  13
5  01-07-2019 13:28:20   Y  12
6  01-07-2019 13:28:20   Z  15
10 01-07-2019 13:50:25   X  13
11 01-07-2019 13:50:25   Y  11
12 01-07-2019 13:50:25   Z  10
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("01-07-2019 13:27:31", "01-07-2019 13:28:20", 
"01-07-2019 13:49:54", "01-07-2019 13:50:25"), class = "factor"), 
    var = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L), .Label = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), val = c(5L, 
    10L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 13L, 11L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this:

1. Create a dataset filtering out values of X<=10 and Y>=15. Then you just need to check that there is a value for X and Y left in the dataset for each timestamp. 
   You can check which values for var are left in the dataset for each time using dataset[, anyX := any(var=="X"), by = time]
2. Reshape the dataset into wide format and then it is trivial to check both conditions at once. You will need to also check for NA's. This method assumes you can't have multiple values for each value of var at a timestamp.
3. Filter the dataset to select the timestamps that have X and Y matching your conditions. Then remove values of X and Y not matching the conditions (This may not be needed if you can't have multiple X and Y at a timestamp.).

```
dt[,outputTime:=any(var=="X"&val>10) | any(var=="Y"&val<15),by=time][outputTime==TRUE][,outputTime:=NULL][var=="X"&val>10|var=="Y"&val<10|var=="Z"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```
# Define helper function foo:
foo <- function(x, y) any(x == "X" & y > 10) & any(x == "Y" & y < 15)

DT[, .SD[foo(var, val)], by = time]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tidy Answer

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dataExample <- data.frame(
time = c(
'01-07-2019 13:27:31',
'01-07-2019 13:27:31',
'01-07-2019 13:27:32',
'01-07-2019 13:27:32',
'01-07-2019 13:27:30'),
var = c("X","Y","X","Y","X"),
val = c(4,5,3,5,9))

#Convert from character to date-time
dataExample$time <- dmy_hms(dataExample$time) 

dataExample %>% group_by(time) %>% 
filter((var == "X" & val > 4) | (var == "Y" & val < 8))
```

Returns

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   time [3]
  time                var     val
  <dttm>              <fct> <dbl>
1 2019-07-01 13:27:31 Y         5
2 2019-07-01 13:27:32 Y         5
3 2019-07-01 13:27:30 X         9
```